# Twitter OAuth Showing Timeline Not Tweets

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

Anyone know how I can tweak the settings in the Wordpress theme used in this site (http://www.ethnecity.church.ly/) to make the Twitter section (near the bottom left of the page) show the tweets for the account instead of the timeline from the Twitter account? Note: the plugin is using OAuth...I just don't know how to tell it to display tweets instead of the timeline.

I believe this is the code that displays the twitter info:

```
<?php
$user_screen_name = 'ethnecity';
$user_full_name = '(removed)';

$settings = array(
'consumer_key' => '(removed)',
'consumer_secret' => '(removed)',
'access_token' => '(removed)',
'access_token_secret' => '(removed)');

$api_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json';

$api_params = array(
'count' => 40,
'contributor_details' => 'false',
'include_entities' => 'false');

// OAuth:

function oauth_encode($data){
if(is_array($data)){
return array_map('oauth_encode', $data);
} else if(is_scalar($data)) {
return str_ireplace(array('+', '%7E'), array(' ', '~'), rawurlencode($data));
} else {
return '';
}}

// OAuth base settings

$oauth_params = array(
'oauth_consumer_key' => $settings['consumer_key'],
'oauth_nonce' => md5(microtime() . mt_rand()),
'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
'oauth_token' => $settings['access_token'],
'oauth_version' => '1.0',
);

// Sign OAuth params

$sign_params = array_merge($oauth_params, $api_params);

uksort($sign_params, 'strcmp');

foreach ($sign_params as $k => $v) {
$sparam[] = oauth_encode($k) . '=' . oauth_encode($v);
}
$sparams = implode('&', $sparam);

$base_string = 'GET&' . oauth_encode($api_url) . '&' . oauth_encode($sparams);

$signing_key = oauth_encode($settings['consumer_secret']) . '&' .     oauth_encode($settings['access_token_secret']);

$oauth_params['oauth_signature'] = oauth_encode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_string,     $signing_key, TRUE)));


// Set Authorization header:

uksort($oauth_params, 'strcmp');

foreach ($oauth_params as $k => $v) {
$hparam[] = $k . '="' . $v . '"';
}

$hparams = implode(', ', $hparam);

$headers = array();
$headers['Expect'] = '';
$headers['Authorization'] = 'OAuth ' . $hparams;

foreach ($headers as $k => $v) {
$curlheaders[] = trim($k . ': ' . $v);
}

// Format params:

foreach ($api_params as $k => $v) {
$rparam[] = $k . '=' . $v;
}
$rparams = implode('&', $rparam);


// echo "curl --get '" . $api_url . "' --data '" . $rparams . "' --header 'Authorization:         OAuth " . $hparams . "' --verbose" . PHP_EOL;


// GET:

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url . '?' . $rparams);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlheaders);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10 );

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
$errno = curl_errno($ch);
curl_close($ch);


function get_twitterfeeds(){
global $code; global $response;

if($code != 200){

//echo 'Error' . PHP_EOL;
//echo $code . PHP_EOL;
//print_r($response);
//print_r($info);

} else {
 $all = json_decode($response, true);
 //echo '<pre />';
// print_r($all);
 //exit;
return $all;
}

}




?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be modified so as to retrieve user's timeline. As per the current code it should return only tweets present on your timeline.

If you need only your's or a particular user's feed , your code should be modified in such a way that resource URL should be changed.

```
    $api_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json';
    $api_params = array(
                 'screen_name' => 'ethnecity'
                 'count' => 40,
                 'contributor_details' => 'false',
                  'include_entities' => 'false'
                 );
```

Please verify the document https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline